# Transforming the union of two complements.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$  two subsets of a set $Z$ such that
$$A\cap B=\emptyset$$
Suppose there are subsets $X,Y,A',B'$ of $Z$ such that
$$A=X\setminus A' \;\; \text{and}\;\;B=Y\setminus B' $$
Is there any way to transform the expression
$$\big (X\setminus A'\big) \cup \big (Y\setminus B'\big )\;\;(*)$$

Comment: $A\cup B$?  What sort of transformation are you wanting if not this?

Comment: I know my question is not precise but I wanted to know if there is something known (maybe some distributivity properties, even in terms of $Z$) that can be done to change this expression into something that can be useful for me ?

Comment: Again.... What is unsatisfactory about writing it as $A\cup B$?  Why even mention $X,Y$ in the first place?

Comment: My question is originally topological, I want to write $A\cup B$ as the union of closed subsets of $Z$, given that $X,Y,A',B'$ are all closed in $Z$.